# Office 365 / Outlook Web App easier delivery receipt and read receipt (Bookmarklet)

Tags: javascript, jquery, outlook, office365, bookmarklet

Ok, so this is an answer, not a question. Since you simply cannot turn on automatic read and delivery receipts in the Outlook Web App, I turned to javascript to make it easier for some of our users. This will reduce the number of needed clicks from 6 to 1.

I'm running this jquery code as a bookmarklet, tested in IE11 and Chrome.

```
$('button').filter(function(){ return $(this).attr('title') == 'More commands'; }).delay(100).click();
$('span').filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'Show message options...'; }).delay(200).click();
$('span').filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'Request a delivery receipt'; }).delay(300).click();
$('span').filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'Request a read receipt'; }).delay(500).click();
$('span').filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'OK'; }).delay(600).click();
```

As a bookmarklet, it's wrapped in a little bit of messy code, but it gets the job done.

```
javascript:void function(){$("button").filter(function(){return"More commands"==$(this).attr("title")}).delay(100).click(),$("span").filter(function(){return"Show message options..."==$(this).text()}).delay(200).click(),$("span").filter(function(){return"Request a delivery receipt"==$(this).text()}).delay(300).click(),$("span").filter(function(){return"Request a read receipt"==$(this).text()}).delay(500).click(),$("span").filter(function(){return"OK"==$(this).text()}).delay(600).click()}();
```

Save that as a bookmark and run it when composing a message in the Outlook Web App, and it will programatically click all the necessary buttons to request a read receipt and a delivery receipt.

I wanted to document this somewhere conspicuous because the only answer to this problem as of yet is that Microsoft isn't doing anything about the problem, and there is no sign that they intend to.

Comment: Please do not create "documentation" in this manner. When you want to answer a question, please submit and actual question and then choose to answer your own question when creating it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Thanks for trying to share the solution you've found to a problem. Please follow the format, however. You can post a question and then answer it yourself, but the solution should be below, not in the body of the question.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes - in addition, the fact that there *isn't* an answer available readily through google, means that the underlying question is probably a very good one for SO! You might find someone ready to help you with a more elegant answer than what you've provided.